# Reading child in Firebase Database

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I want to access child item in users according to particular key of child node and I have passed that key in my function getcount() but when I am accessing the user with that referal key it is showing up com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String.

I have used the following code but it is not working properly
[image]

```
  private void getCount(final String referalKey) {
    DatabaseReference myref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(referalKey);
    myref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            user u=dataSnapshot.getValue(user.class);
            Toast.makeText(Home.this,u.getCount(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



}
```

my user model class

```
public class user {
      public String name;
      public String phone;
      public String refphone;
      public String address;
      public String count;

    public user() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public user(String name, String phone, String refphone, String address, String count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.refphone = refphone;
        this.address = address;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public void setRefphone(String refphone) {
        this.refphone = refphone;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getRefphone() {
        return refphone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your `user` model

Comment: i have already added my user model class

Comment: Where? I don't see it

Comment: I mean `User.java`, not database structure

Comment: check now I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i can see in your database Screenshot your count and phone number in one of the document it's in `"` and on other it's long. Change it manually

Comment: Yes that was the main thing I missed that double quotes while entering the data that made incorrect matching of datatypes Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Change your `phone` and `count` property from `String` to `long` as your database contain it as `long`

```
public class user {
    public String name;
    public long phone;
    public String refphone;
    public String address;
    public long count;

    public user() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(long count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public user(String name, long phone, String refphone, String address, long count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.refphone = refphone;
        this.address = address;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPhone(long phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public void setRefphone(String refphone) {
        this.refphone = refphone;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public long getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getRefphone() {
        return refphone;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't work even if he uses your user model. Cause the problem with insertion in database. He needs to change in manually from database or delete nodes which are in string

Comment: yes that was the problem in insertion of data in database thanks for your answers